# The dense subgroup of ${\mathrm{Gal}}(\overline{{\Bbb Q}_p}/{\Bbb Q}_p)$.

Tags: group-theory, galois-theory, p-adic-number-theory, noncommutative-algebra, local-field

Let us consider the absolute Galois group ${\mathrm{Gal}}(\overline{{\Bbb Q}_p}/{\Bbb Q}_p)$ of the local field ${\Bbb Q}_p$. It is widely-known that ${\mathrm{Gal}}(\overline{{\Bbb Q}_p}/{\Bbb Q}_p)$ is topologically generated by two elements. That is, we have a certain di-generated discrete subgroup $L_p < {\mathrm{Gal}}(\overline{{\Bbb Q}_p}/{\Bbb Q}_p)$ such that the profinite completion of $L_p$ becomes ${\mathrm{Gal}}(\overline{{\Bbb Q}_p}/{\Bbb Q}_p)$.

Q. Is $L_p$ indepenedent of $p$? I.e., does it hold that $L_p \cong L_q$ for $p \not=q$?

Comment: Probably providing a reference with an exact statement of the "widely-known" fact would help. If you're thinking of the Wingberg-Jannsen theorem, then this presentation by Neukirch shows several of the relations depending on $p$: http://www.numdam.org/item/AST_1982__94__153_0.pdf. By the way, there is probably not just one ("the") dense subgroup in such a Galois group.

Comment: Then again, you cannot mean that presentation because it has more generators.

Comment: @Pierre MATSUMI   Don't you make a confusion between the absolute Galois group of Q_p and its maximal pro-p- quotient ?

Comment: In a compact group "discrete subgroup" is the same as "finite subgroup". What you can "discrete subgroup" is rather a dense subgroup. And actually, purely at the level of pro-$p$-group, the assertion is incorrect: if $\Gamma$ is a dense subgroup of a pro-$p$ group $G$, the embedding map $\Gamma\to G$ is not necessarily the pro-$p$ completion (i.e., the pro-$p$ completion can be "much larger").

Comment: Let us replace each local field ${\Bbb Q}_p$ with ${\Bbb Q}_p(\zeta_{\infty})$, i.e., the field adjoined with ALL roots of unity. Then among Galois groups ${\mathrm{Gal}}(\overline{{\Bbb Q}_p}/{\Bbb Q}_p(\zeta_{\infty}))$ over all prime p's, can we find some common dense subgroup $M$? As far as I read the above comments cyclotomic extensions may be the bar from finding ``M''.

Comment: Most likely tame part will be troublesome. If we focus on wild inertia, dense subgroup could be common for all $p$'s.